# How can I draw a scatter plot using matplotlib, each x_tick for one column

Tags: matplotlib

I have a dataset like:

```
a1 = [81, 42, 73, 94, 85, 66]
a2 = [63, 55, 79, 65, 94, 76]
a3 = [3, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6]
```

I want to draw a scatter plot that the x_ticks will be 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'
and the each y_tick is the data in a1, a2 and a3.
for example above a1 x_tick there's 6 dots.[81, 42, 73, 94, 85, 66]

EDIT: Sorry it was a stupid question, and my words aren't explicit as well, I was just trying to draw a simple box plot.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the y-ticks are? As you wrote it, it is very vague

Comment: Sorry the y_ticks would just be simple numbers like 10, 20, 30, ··· 100

Comment: could you show some desired output or a schematic image of the plot that clarifies your task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I could make of the question, this could be one simple implementation:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a1 = [81, 42, 73, 94, 85, 66]
a2 = [63, 55, 79, 65, 94, 76]
a3 = [3, 5, 4, 8, 7, 6]

plt.scatter(x=[0]*len(a1), y=a1)
plt.scatter(x=[1]*len(a2), y=a2)
plt.scatter(x=[2]*len(a3), y=a3)

plt.xticks(ticks=[0,1,2], labels=["a1", "a2", "a3"])

plt.show()
```

With the following output:
[image]

If you also want to only display the y values at the y axis you can add this line:
`plt.yticks(ticks=a1+a2+a3, labels=a1+a2+a3)`

But for y values that are very close to each other (see values for `a3`) this will get crowded.

Comment: This works! Thx for spending time for that unclear question lol,